# Navigation Problem with AndroidStudio (Kotlin)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I wanna a help ,i am facing issue and I don't how to solve. I design a splash screen after 5 seconds should navigate to another activity my problem was if I pressed on the splash screen during the navigation to the second activity the app went to background.
the time to create the home activity was 300ms if i pressed the spalsh activity during this time for creating the home activity the APP went to background.

```kotlin
class Main : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var enabled = true
    var onetime = false
    var response = 0
    private var myshered: SharedPreferences? = null
    private var mDelayHandler: Handler? = null
    private val sPlash: Long = 5000 //6 seconds
    private val mRunnable: Runnable = Runnable {
        if (!isFinishing) {
            test()
        }

    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        )
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen)
        //Initialize the Handler
        mDelayHandler = Handler()
        //Navigate with delay
        mDelayHandler!!.postDelayed(mRunnable, sPlash)

    }

    public override fun onDestroy() {

        if (mDelayHandler != null) {
            mDelayHandler!!.removeCallbacks(mRunnable)
        }
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
    }

    fun test() {

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://168.128.33.104:80/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
        val api: ApiService = retrofit.create(ApiService::class.java)
        api.getdata("updates/apiv1/articles/")
        val call = api.getnew("updates/apiv1/articles/")
        call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<ArticleData>> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ArticleData>>, t: Throwable) {
                enable(false)
                Toast.makeText(this@Main, "Unable to connect to server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                val it = Intent(this@Main, Home::class.java)
                startActivity(it)
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<ArticleData>>,
                response: Response<List<ArticleData>>
            ) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    enable(false)
                    getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    );
                    lgnsucess = true
                    News = response.body()!!
                    val it = Intent(this@Main, Home::class.java)
                    it.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                    startActivity(it)
                } else {
                    enable(false)
                    getWindow().setFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                    );
                    lgnsucess = false
                    val it = Intent(this@Main, Home::class.java)
                    startActivity(it)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    companion object {
        var lgnsucess = false
        var News: List<ArticleData> = emptyList()
    }

    fun enable(b: Boolean) {
        enabled = b
    }

    override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
        return if (enabled) super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev) else true
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Youness, welcome to StackOverflow. 

I see you are trying to learn Android development. Android has come a long way in terms of how  app should be developed. I would encourage you to learn [basics](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp) first, also take a look at Google's [sunflower sample app](https://github.com/android/sunflower/) to get a better understanding.

As for the issue you are having, I am not very clear on what the objective is - pressing back should destroy your splash screen and take the user back to the home screen.

Comment: thank you for your comment , i think i am not clear in my description ,  Mr@HossainKhan , my problem was if the user pressed back button twice the app do it functions but the app went to background . if the user press one time the activity is destroyed and the back to home screen

Comment: Thank you @HossainKhan I solved my problem the problem was the style of APP.

Comment: Glad to know that! Good luck learning.